# Parse date in pandas with unit='D'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing, timestamp

What is wrong with this?

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01',unit='D')
```

If I do it without the unit

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01')
```

no error is raised. However, insted of the standard unit `ns` I rather want `D`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quite clear description and examples on the [official documentaiton](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).
Let's take an example from it:

```python
pd.to_datetime([1, 2, 3], unit='D',
               origin=pd.Timestamp('1960-01-01'))
```

###### Output:

```console
DatetimeIndex(['1960-01-02', '1960-01-03', '1960-01-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

What has happened here? Basically we are taking `origin` as the base date, and this `list` in the beginning as a… multiplier? By `unit='D'` we set it to days, no problem, let's see how it behaves on a different `list`:

```python
pd.to_datetime([0, 30, 64], unit='D',
               origin=pd.Timestamp('1960-01-01'))
```

###### Output:

```console
DatetimeIndex(['1960-01-01', '1960-01-31', '1960-03-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Now look. **0** means there is no change.
**30** means we are adding 30 days to our starting date.
Finally **64** means we are adding 64 days to our base date.

Let's do it in Excel:

| var | value |
| --- | --- |
| Base= | 01-01-60 |
| +64 | 05-03-60 |

[image]

So, feels legit, does not it?
Let's try it on some different unit, e.g. `s` which stands for **seconds**:

```python
pd.to_datetime([0, 30, 64], unit='s',
               origin=pd.Timestamp('1960-01-01'))
```

###### Output:

```console
DatetimeIndex(['1960-01-01 00:00:00', '1960-01-01 00:00:30',
               '1960-01-01 00:01:04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

That was expected. Basically same thing, we are rather taking the base value, or add **30 seconds** or get **00:01:04** by adding **64 seconds**

## To sum it up

You are misusing this `unit=` key, it's meant to add up to the base datetime by providing a `list` of values of how much you want to add up. Your date should be featured in `origin=` key as `origin='2022-01-01'`.

If you don't want this functionality and you want to cast this value to a `day`, than look at the other answer. Basically:

```python
pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d').day
```

###### Output:

```console
1
```

One is the first day of Jan 2022.

## Update

From the comments I remember you wanted to cast your datetime with seconds to  date. You can do it with `.ceil('1D')`.